Sum of alternating binomial coefficients for $n=6k$ and/or $n=6k+4$ [closed, rewritten in other question]
I have a simple problem, but I don't know a way to prove (or disprove) it.
I wonder if this problem is known already or if the solution can be found somewhere. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this or know any reference that answers the following problem?
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove (or disprove) that: if $n=6k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (or $n=6k+4$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$), then there is no non-empty subset $I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $\sum_{i\in I} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} = 0$.
The statement is trivially not true when $n$ is odd, since for any $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ we have $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n}{n-i}$, so, we can just simply pick $I=\{i,n-i\}$.
I also notice that the statement is not true for $n=6k+2$,  as we have
$$\binom{6k+2}{2k+1}=2\binom{6k+2}{2k}=\binom{6k+2}{2k}+\binom{6k+2}{4k+2}$$
which implies for $I=\{2k,2k+1,4k+2\}$, we get $$\sum_{i\in I} (-1)^i \binom{6k+2}{i} = \binom{6k+2}{2k} -\binom{6k+2}{2k+1} +\binom{6k+2}{4k+2} = 0.$$
But, somehow, I believe that the statement is true for $n=6k$ (and $n=6k+4$).
Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? Thank you.
update: considering that I found some counter-examples for this problem, I posted an updated version of this problem here

What about $0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom ni$?

@AndreaMori Yes, that one is true for all positive integer $n$. But, I am interested in the case when $i=0$ is excluded. In other words, if we only consider $i=1,2,\dots,n$, could we find some $i$s in such a way that the alternating sum is also $0$ if evaluated only on those $i$s. This is trivially possible if $n$ is odd. I also mentioned that it is also possible for $n=6k+2$. But, somehow I cannot find such $i$s for $n=6k$ and $n=6k+4$. This makes me think that maybe it is somehow impossible for those cases, but I have no idea on how to prove it (if it is true).

I believe there is a counter example for $n=24=6\cdot 4$. The subset is $I=\{3,4,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,20\}$.
I used a python script to find it (and in fact it found several other subsets for $n=24$) by generating the particular row of Pascal's triangle and looking at all possible subset sums. Then I independently verified any hits using just the sum of binomials.

Thank you, I did Magma programming to confirm that. Also, up to $n=30$, only $n=24$ fulfills the condition with two sets $I_1={3,4,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,20}$ and $I_2={2,5,6,7,9,10,11,14,18,22}$. So, because of this I restated the problem here just in case someone can find more counter examples or can prove it for $n=6k+4$.

I have several other subsets for $n=24$ that sums to $0$. I would need to check what those subsets are, and if you want I can post them here.

are you sure? because I did a complete search and only find those two. Also, I found a counter-example for $n=34$. I will update it here

Let me verify again. I will update accordingly.

@StevenSurya I have found $48$ subsets for $n=24$ :D Would you like me to provide a list?

could you give me just two or three of them (other than $I_1$ and $I_2$ that i mentioned)? I will check it tomorrow. Thank you.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
